# Translate the same object multiple times in the same storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a two part animation that slides an object out into the middle of the screen, pauses, and then slides to a certain spot, shrinking it to nothing. It crashes when running the storyboard, is it not possible to do two different translatetransforms on the same object in the same storyboard?

As a fix I tried splitting up the animation into two storyboards, however I ran into another issue. When the first part finishes the card resets back to the starting position in the corner as if the animation never happened. Then my second storyboard kicks after a few seconds. If the position didn't reset afterwards it would be fine.

So how I can either get it run all in one storyboard like below, or else not have it reset the position after completing the part 1 animation if I split it into two storyboards.

The code below will only work if I remove the second translatetransform animation from part 2.

```
public void SendCardToPile(UIElement bigCard, UIElement targetElement)
{
    this.ZoomDropShadowImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    // setup
    var _Scale = new ScaleTransform
    {
        ScaleX = 1.0,
        ScaleY = 1.0,
        CenterX = 0,
        CenterY = 0
    };

    this.ZoomItemCard.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    var _Translate = new TranslateTransform();
    var _Group = new TransformGroup();
    _Group.Children.Add(_Scale);
    _Group.Children.Add(_Translate);
    bigCard.RenderTransform = _Group;

    // animate
    var _Storyboard = new Storyboard { };
    var _Storyboard2 = new Storyboard { };

    var transform = targetElement.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement);
    Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

    // Part 1 **************************

    // translate (location X)
    var _TranslateAnimateX = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        From = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / 2),
        To = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - 250) / 2,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateX);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateX, _Translate);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateX,
        new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

    // translate (location Y)
    var _TranslateAnimateY = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        From = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 400) / 2,
        To = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 400) / 2,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateY);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateY, _Translate);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateY,
        new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

    // Part 2 **************************
    double stopDelay = 2;
    double disappearSpeed = .5;

    // scale X
    var _ScaleAnimateX = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay),
        To = 0.0,
        From = 1.0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(disappearSpeed)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateX);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateX, _Scale);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateX,
        new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));

    // scale Y
    var _ScaleAnimateY = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay),
        To = 0.0,
        From = 1.0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(disappearSpeed)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateY);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateY, _Scale);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateY,
        new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));

    // translate (location X)
    var _TranslateAnimateX2 = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay),
        To = absolutePosition.X,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(disappearSpeed)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateX2);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateX2, _Translate);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateX2,
        new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

    // translate (location Y)
    var _TranslateAnimateY2 = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay),
        To = absolutePosition.Y,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(disappearSpeed)
    };
    _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateY2);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateY2, _Translate);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateY2,
        new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

    // finalize
    //EventHandler eh = null;
    //eh = (s, args) =>
    //{
    //    _Storyboard.Completed -= eh;
    //};
    //_Storyboard.Completed += eh;

    _Storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: `It crashes when running the storyboard, is it not possible to do two different translatetransforms on the same object in the same storyboard?` Yes, it is possible. Would help if you could post the exact error you see when it crashes.

Comment: It doesn't really give anything useful. It just breaks at the storyboard.begin with:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the animation I wanted with a single storyboard using keyframes

```
    public void SendCardToPile(UIElement bigCard, UIElement targetElement)
    {
        this.ZoomDropShadowImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        double stopDelay = 2;
        double disappearSpeed = .5;

        // setup
        var _Scale = new ScaleTransform
        {
            ScaleX = 1.0,
            ScaleY = 1.0,
            CenterX = 0,
            CenterY = 0
        };

        this.ZoomItemCard.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        var _Translate = new TranslateTransform();
        var _Group = new TransformGroup();
        _Group.Children.Add(_Scale);
        _Group.Children.Add(_Translate);
        bigCard.RenderTransform = _Group;

        // animate
        var _Storyboard = new Storyboard { };

        var transform = targetElement.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement);
        Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        // translate (location X)
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _TranslateAnimateX = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateX, _Translate);
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateX, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)),
            Value = -(Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / 2),
        });

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)),
            Value = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - 250) / 2
        });

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay)),
            Value = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - 250) / 2
        });

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay + disappearSpeed)),
            Value = absolutePosition.X
        });

        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateX);

        // translate (location Y)
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _TranslateAnimateY = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateY, _Translate);
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateY, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));

        _TranslateAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)),
            Value = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 400) / 2
        });

        _TranslateAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.25)),
            Value = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 400) / 2
        });

        _TranslateAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay)),
            Value = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth - 400) / 2
        });

        _TranslateAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay + disappearSpeed)),
            Value = absolutePosition.Y
        });

        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateY);

        // scale X
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _ScaleAnimateX = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateX, _Scale);
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateX, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));

        _ScaleAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay)),
            Value = 1.0
        });

        _ScaleAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay + disappearSpeed)),
            Value = 0.0
        });

        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateX);

        // scale Y
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _ScaleAnimateY = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(_ScaleAnimateY, _Scale);
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_ScaleAnimateY, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));

        _ScaleAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay)),
            Value = 1.0
        });

        _ScaleAnimateY.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopDelay + disappearSpeed)),
            Value = 0.0
        });

        _Storyboard.Children.Add(_ScaleAnimateY);

        // finalize
        //EventHandler eh = null;
        //eh = (s, args) =>
        //{
        //    _Storyboard.Completed -= eh;
        //};
        //_Storyboard.Completed += eh;


        _Storyboard.Begin();
    }
```